# Why this causing Heap corruption?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why this piece of code causing Heap corruption when trying to delete[] fullname variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    const int size = 255;
    char* firstname = new char[size];
    char* lastname = new char[size];
    cin.getline(firstname, size, '\n');
    cin.getline(lastname, size, '\n');

    int fullnamesize = strlen(firstname) + strlen(lastname) + 2;
    cout << "fullname size: " << fullnamesize;
    char* fullname = new char[fullnamesize];
    strcpy_s(fullname, size, firstname);
    strcat_s(fullname, size, " ");
    strcat_s(fullname, size, lastname);

    cout << "full name: " << fullname << "\n" ;

    delete[] fullname;
    delete[] firstname;
    delete[] lastname;  

    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot find what wrong with this dellocation...

Comment: Shouldn't `fullnamesize` be used in these `strcpy_s()`,`strcat_s()` function calls?

Comment: You tagged this as `C`, but there is no such thing as `new[]` or `cout` in the `C` language.

Comment: You allocated the correct amount of space for `fullname`, since you know the `strlen` of both first and last name, plus the space character.  Simple, straightforward `strcpy` and `strcat` calls should / would have worked.

Comment: Because you failed to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with it?
It actually goes wrong at strcpy_s.  Because strcpy_s overwrites the target buffer first (to the size specified in the function call).  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx -

> The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFE.
>   To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

(That is quite subtle I admit!)

And you have the wrong size for the target buffer so your memory is overwritten as you've allocated only just enough memory for the fullname, but the size parameters you are passing are larger.

**Why does it crash at delete[] rather than strncpy?**

There's nothing wrong with the deallocation at delete[]. The problem has occurred before you get there.

The program has no idea that you've passed the wrong size in.  But the strcpy function overwrites a memory management structure in the heap.  This doesn't cause any problems until the delete[] call.  Delete tries to use the information and discovers it's corrupt.  Then you get a crash.

In a big program this type of problem is a complete nightmare.

**What's the right approach?**

Using the safe string functions is a great idea, but you'll need to read the manual for them carefully to ensure that you get the right result.  And be much more careful about the size you are passing to them.

*PS. The old strcpy and char * approach is important to understand, but in the long run, for robust code, investigate std::string*

Comment: in that case the program should fail in strcpy/strcat. why it fail in the delete[] ?

Comment: @Shelef Undefined behavior fails wherever it want's to.

Comment: The program has no idea that you've passed the wrong size in.  It then overwrites a structure in the heap when you call strcpy_s.  Then, when you get to the delete[] function it tries to use the information and discovers it's corrupt.  In a big program this type of problem is a complete nightmare.

Comment: @JCx add that comment to the answer. Well worth bringing to the attention of a new programmer.

Comment: There you go!  Updated.

Comment: @Shelef `in that case the program should fail in strcpy/strcat`  Catching buffer overwrites in "real time" is not how the VC++ debug runtime works.  The VC++ debug runtime library checks if the memory is ok *after* you are finished with it (when you call `delete[]`).  That is when it knew that you overwrote the buffer.  It checks something called "guard bytes" that trail the actual memory you allocated -- if the guard bytes have been altered, then it is assumed you overwrote the buffer.